# Hide / Fade In effect - cross browser?

Tags: jquery, html

I have just an hour to think of a few classy looking effects to add to a high end clients site - the easiest of which I thought would be to add a simple fade in effect.

Only thing that worries me is it needs to be highly cross-browser/cross tablet functional is there any argument that the following script could be detrimental to the site?

The .main-wrap div surrounds all the main page content (not including nav or background) so the following script should just load in all content once page has loaded -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.main-wrap').hide();
    $('.main-wrap').fadeIn(4000);    
});
```

I figured that if the client browser had poor javascript support - then the .main-wrap wouldnt hide in the first place and i cant think of any other negative - but if anyone else can please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

I must say you can chain it for better performance (*No need to call same selector twice*):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.main-wrap').hide().fadeIn(4000);    
});
```

*`it needs to be highly cross-browser/cross tablet functional`* As we know these days mobile devices are having better browsers which have better html5/css3 compatibility and fully functional. So there must not be any issue. Yet that need a well thought js work. as i mentioned above better will be to cache the selectors for use in multiple areas in the code.

Answer (score 2):

if you initially add `display:none` in the class definition css then there is no need to call **$('.main-wrap').hide();** and your code will work as expected

```
.main-wrap
{
    display: none;
}
```